# how to sort and update unique key from another key in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a problem to sort my Unique Key after add a new entry in to my table ...
for example i have std_id for Students IDs as unique key and also std_fname and std_lname for Students First Name and Students Last Name, i want when i add new student to MySQL table, previous std_id update to new one sorted by Last Name ...
I test many ways to do that but i couldn't found any answer ... I'm new in PHP

This code just works  for the first entry from second entry all std_id changed to std_pk actually the third part not execute after first entry

std_pk is my Primary Key and it's auto increment

thanks

this is one of many ways that i test ...

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT std_id FROM std_list");
//first i set all unique std_id to my Auto Increment Primary Key std_pk 
while ( $a_row = mysql_fetch_row( $query ) ) 
{
    $a_row=mysql_query("UPDATE `std_list` SET std_id = std_pk WHERE std_id != std_pk ");
};

//second i use ORDER BY to sort std_id by std_lname
$query=mysql_query("SELECT std_id  FROM std_list ORDER BY std_lname");

$x = 1;

//and third i use a value to set previous std_id to new one, $x is new std_id
while ( $a_row = mysql_fetch_row( $query ) ) 
    {
        $a_row=mysql_query("UPDATE std_list SET std_id = $x WHERE std_id = std_pk ");
        $x = $x + 1 ;
    };
```

Comment: comments are `//`, not `\\\`

Comment: ;) i wrote them very quickly

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to query the db and get a sorted list of students.

To do that, instead of re-ordering the keys, you should change your sql query and add an order-by clause.

See: Sorting Rows on the MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: thanks for you answer but i need to update student ID ... for example before i add Alex , Benjamin was in list and his id is 1 but now id 1 is for Alex and 2 is for Benjamin (sort by alphabet)

Comment: @vahid why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: i want to my students list sorted by alphabet and every students have an id from sorted list ... when a new student come in all list updated and new id generated for all students

Comment: Why do you want to re-generate the id?

Comment: because id must sorted by alphabet (last name)

Comment: What are you using that id for?

Comment: everyone must have an id for other works out of computer and system